# Federated domain user cannot signin to windows laptop

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, domaincontroller, microsoft-entra-id, azure-entra-id

We never had Active Directory setup on-premise, the company Identity provider is Google workspace and since we started using Microsoft services (365 and Azure etc) we federated the Google workspace domain to Azure entra ID and since then single sign on working without any issues. I had now joined a windows machine to entra ID organization and during this process I was promoted for username and password, I got redirected to Google to prove my identity and system is now part of a entra ID domain but when I signin to the machine using Azure AD/xxxxx and in the password prompt I am entering my Google password but I see error "username/password is incorrect"